# cleaning up $PATH in bash

Tags: bash, path

My path has a lot of entries that were added long ago by scripts. They are not in my `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bash_login`.

I'm worried that resetting my path in `.bashrc` will have undesirable long-term results. Is there a way to find where things have been added to my path and remove them manually? Are things always added by file or is path cached somewhere? If the latter, is it easy to clean that up?

Comment: Would be better on superuser.com stack exchange site.

Comment: This would also be a good fit for unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to find **who** modified your **PATH** is to run:

```
  $ bash --login -i -xv 2>&1 | grep ' \. '
```

For example I got:

```
+ . /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
        . /etc/bash_completion
++ . /etc/bash_completion
+++ . /etc/bash_completion.d/abook
+++ . /etc/bash_completion.d/ant
+ . /etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh
+ . /etc/profile.d/openssl.sh
+ . /etc/profile.d/qt3-devel.sh
+ . /etc/profile.d/tetex-profile.sh
+ . /etc/profile.d/xinit.sh
+ . /etc/bash.bashrc
```

...

Comment: Also try add **source** word to grep...

Comment: As you get list of **ALL** files that modify behavior of bash you need grep they for **PATH=** pattern...

Comment: As mentioned above, make sure to grep for `source` as well: `bash --login -xv -c "echo" 2>&1 | grep -E " (\.|source) "`.

Comment: It's worth noting that his answer gives you all the files sourced by bash upon login. You still have to look at them individually to see which are setting the PATH variable. You can't easily grep for that (i.e. for PATH), as that information is on different lines in the bash -x output.

Comment: Should I teach you shell programming? Filter file names and pipe it to loop where you `grep -C 5 PATH` and review changes.

Comment: Then feel free to update the answer above accordingly :)

Comment: Fyi. Doesn't work on Windows WSL2 (no deeper checking, just c+p)

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't let some random sysadmin decide what's in your PATH anyway, you should *set it to the PATH you need*. You begin with

```
# POSIX way of getting the system's PATH to POSIX tools:
PATH=$(getconf PATH)   # Or /usr/bin/getconf PATH.
```

followed by whatever you require in addition, e.g.

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

and put this in your shell's `.profile` or equivalent. Note that you *do not* want `.` or world-writable directories in your PATH for security reasons.

Comment: $ getconf PATH results in 
/bin:/usr/bin

I'm not sure what things like /usr/X11R6/bin are or if I still need them in my path. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you don't use the X11 window system (with xterm, firefox, acroread, ...) you don't need /usr/X11R6/bin. If you're unsure, type `ls /usr/X11R6/bin` to see if you need any of the listed executables. I'd say it doesn't hurt to have it in your PATH.

Answer (score 3):

You're always at liberty to look at the directory contents for each component of `$PATH` and decide whether you use the programs therein.  If you don't use the programs, the chances are, you won't be hurt by removing the directory from $PATH.  If the directory doesn't exist, then you can completely safely remove it.

It is puzzling that the directories show up in your profile and related files.  You should check for `~/.profile` too.  You should also look at material like `/etc/profile`.

Personally, I consider I am in charge of my PATH.  I set it from scratch according to my rules, picking the directories I need.  You're not obliged to accept what the system admins set for you, though you should not idly remove PATH components that they've added.  But their views on what's desirable may be different from yours.

The only long-term undesirable effect might be that some program you use stops working because it relied on something from the old version of $PATH.  So, keep a record of what you had before you started messing with PATH - but don't be afraid to adjust PATH to suit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/profile` file, and, depending on your OS version, `/etc/profile.d/` directory.